# PHP Definition MultiDimensional Associative Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have 2 arrays with some sample data and I just want to confirm if I have the terminology correct:

Multidimensional Array:

```
$names = array([
        "name" => "Bob",
        "age" => 25, 
        "level" => 6],
        ["name" => "Joe",
        "age" => 34, 
        "level" => 6]
    );
```

Multidimensional Associative Array:

```
$names = array(
    "Bob" => array(
        "age" => 25, 
        "diploma" => "DAC", 
        "level" => 6),
    "Joe" => array(
        "age" => 34, 
        "diploma" => "DAC", 
        "level" => 6)
    );
```

The second is **Associative** because of the index being the name rather than an index number and **MultiDimensional** because it has more than one entry.

I know it is not really a programming question requiring a code solution, I am just learning the terminology.

Comment: yes, you're right, the latter could also be called nested associative arrays.

Comment: All arrays in PHP are associative. The difference is whether the key is an implicit number or an explicit string (or explicit number, if you want to count that). Yes, you *could* call it the way you do, but the distinction is pretty pointless.

Comment: @deceze saying that all arrays in PHP are associative that is basically across the board with all languages right? not just PHP

Comment: Not really. Languages which do distinguish between *lists* and *dictionaries* (arrays/objects) exist. In fact, PHP is the outlier with its combined ordered associative dictionaries. Lists are merely *indexed by offset*, while dictionaries/objects are key-value *associations*.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add my two cents. All said by others is pretty correct, but:
The main difference from associative arrays and "simple" arrays. With "simple" arrays you can do something like this

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $array ) - 1; $i++ ) {
   $element = $array[ $i ];
   // Do something with $element
}
```

With associative arrays, you cannot do it and, if you want to traverse all the arrays you have to do something like this

```
foreach( $array as $key => $element ) {
    // Do something with $element
}
```

This approach (the foreach) can be applied to the "simple" array too, while the first can be applied ONLY to "simple" array

Multidimensional array are simply arrays with AT LEAST one element that is an array, no matter the "type"

By the way, it's always think about arrays as associative arrays, always. It prevents you some very simple mistakes later on

Comment: Nice example - thanks and the explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays are multidimensional associative array.

But in second array you can get details of Bob or Joe by just using their name as key. For example to get details of Bob you can just call:

```
$names['Bob']
```

In first array you have to know the id or index of array to which Bob details were stored.

Comment: That makes sense - didn't really think about it that way before, because the second example has arrays within arrays explicitly so I thought they where called something different

Comment: I think instead second array easy to use OOP